# Change image in PDF

Tags: php, pdf

Hi I keep getting this error:
Runtime Deprecated code usage - Imagick::clone method is deprecated and it's use should be avoided

It is always around this function:

```
protected function ImagePngAlpha($file, $x, $y, $wpx, $hpx, $w, $h, $type, $link, $align, $resize, $dpi, $palign, $filehash='') {
        if (empty($filehash)) {
            $filehash = md5($file);
        }
        // create temp image file (without alpha channel)
        $tempfile_plain = K_PATH_CACHE.'mskp_'.$filehash;
        // create temp alpha file
        $tempfile_alpha = K_PATH_CACHE.'mska_'.$filehash;
        if (extension_loaded('imagick')) { // ImageMagick
            // ImageMagick library
            $img = new Imagick();
            $img->readImage($file);
            // clone image object
            $imga = $img->clone();
            // extract alpha channel
            $img->separateImageChannel(8); // 8 = (imagick::CHANNEL_ALPHA | imagick::CHANNEL_OPACITY | imagick::CHANNEL_MATTE);
            $img->negateImage(true);
            $img->setImageFormat('png');
            $img->writeImage($tempfile_alpha);
            // remove alpha channel
            $imga->separateImageChannel(39); // 39 = (imagick::CHANNEL_ALL & ~(imagick::CHANNEL_ALPHA | imagick::CHANNEL_OPACITY | imagick::CHANNEL_MATTE));
            $imga->setImageFormat('png');
            $imga->writeImage($tempfile_plain);
        } else { // GD library
            // generate images
            $img = imagecreatefrompng($file);
            $imgalpha = imagecreate($wpx, $hpx);
            // generate gray scale palette (0 -> 255)
            for ($c = 0; $c < 256; ++$c) {
                ImageColorAllocate($imgalpha, $c, $c, $c);
            }
            // extract alpha channel
            for ($xpx = 0; $xpx < $wpx; ++$xpx) {
                for ($ypx = 0; $ypx < $hpx; ++$ypx) {
                    $color = imagecolorat($img, $xpx, $ypx);
                    $alpha = ($color >> 24); // shifts off the first 24 bits (where 8x3 are used for each color), and returns the remaining 7 allocated bits (commonly used for alpha)
                    $alpha = (((127 - $alpha) / 127) * 255); // GD alpha is only 7 bit (0 -> 127)
                    $alpha = $this->getGDgamma($alpha); // correct gamma
                    imagesetpixel($imgalpha, $xpx, $ypx, $alpha);
                }
            }
            imagepng($imgalpha, $tempfile_alpha);
            imagedestroy($imgalpha);
            // extract image without alpha channel
            $imgplain = imagecreatetruecolor($wpx, $hpx);
            imagecopy($imgplain, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $wpx, $hpx);
            imagepng($imgplain, $tempfile_plain);
            imagedestroy($imgplain);
        }
        // embed mask image
        $imgmask = $this->Image($tempfile_alpha, $x, $y, $w, $h, 'PNG', '', '', $resize, $dpi, '', true, false);
        // embed image, masked with previously embedded mask
        $this->Image($tempfile_plain, $x, $y, $w, $h, $type, $link, $align, $resize, $dpi, $palign, false, $imgmask);
        // remove temp files
        unlink($tempfile_alpha);
        unlink($tempfile_plain);
    }
```

All I was trying to do is change the image inside the PDF, but for some reason it won't allow me. I tried looking online but I could not find the same issue. Can anyone help please?

Comment: Look at the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.clone.php :P

Comment: I saw this url before, it doesn't provide much help, there is only one example. @Vossen

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the [Imagick::clone documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.clone.php), this method is indeed deprecated, and to be replace by an [object cloning](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php).

Replace the line `$imga = $img->clone();` by `$imga = clone $img;`

Comment: I tried that I get this error now:  Fatal Error - Failed to read the file on line 7879 which is: `   $img->writeImage($tempfile_alpha);`

Comment: @john Check if the path you've got in `$tempfile_alpha` is valid. By the way, it's a different question, you should ask it in a new one.